# Loop counter behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble understanding why the counter variable even though incremented within
the nested loop, is not having any effect on the number of times the parent loop runs!

The code below gives the output `0 1 2` when the increment inside the nested loop is supposed to stop it from executing the second and the third time.

```
for i in range(3):
  print(i)
  for j in range(2):
    i = i + 2
```

Is the `i` inside the nested for pointing to a different `i`!

Comment: you iterate over range object, what do you expect?

Comment: it doesn't work that way in python.

Comment: @SashSinha why should the "i" be reassigned each time the loop runs ! my understanding with loops is that "i" would be initialised on the loop start and then onward work with the value. has it something to do with the range call, like its creating a contextual "i" !

Comment: @isnvi23h4 a new scope isn't created there (unlike with, for example, a function), `i` will take each next value from the sequence and whatever it was before will be lost

Comment: No, that is not how the `for` loop in Python works. It consumes an item from an iterable and assigns the item to the iteration variable, then runs the code in the block. This is repeated until the iterable is exhausted.

Comment: `i` is assigned a value *from* the `range` object's iterator at the start of each iteration; it isn't initialized once when the loop first starts.

Comment: I suggest you read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop is a fancy kind of assignment statement; the loop index is assigned to at the start of each iteration.

The code

```
for i in range(3):
  print(i)
  for j in range(2):
    i = i + 2
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
itr1 = iter(range(3))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(itr1)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    itr2 = iter(range(2))
    while True:
        try:
            j = next(itr2)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        i = i + 2
```

The assignment `i = next(itr1)` ignores anything else done to `i` in the previous iteration: the value depends only on the state of `itr1`, not the current value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

if you display `i` *after* the loop incrementing it, you'll see the change

```py
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    for _ in range(2):  # j is not used
        i += 2
    print(i)  # I'm new!
```

each time the first line runs, it'll re-tag `i` with the next value from the `range()` sequence, discarding what it was before

Answer (score 1):

You don't store the result of the increment anywhere. It goes like this: `i` is assigned a value from `range()`, you print it, then `j` gets the assigned value, `i += 1`, and then you loop starts again, and `i` is assigned the next value from the `range()`.
This should work though

```
for i in range(3):

  for j in range(2):
     
    i = i + 2
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect you are looking for you would have to increment the iterator. You might think of it as incrementing the pointer, rather than the value at the pointer:

```
iterator = iter(range(123))

for i in iterator:
    print(i)
    next(iterator, None) #None here is a default, 
                         #and stops you getting an error if there is no 'next'.
```

Imagine a for loop in python is doing something like the following,  which makes it very obvious why a value assigned to `i` within the body of the loop is lost.  You are incrementing `i` when you really want to increment `n`

```
iterator = list(range(10))
n = 0
while n < len(iterator):
    n+=1
    i = iterator[n]
    print(i)
    i = i+1
```